# Java - Unable to read inside the recordset contained with if else statement

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, recordset

I have a piece of java code that I am not sure as to why I am not getting any results from it. The code goes as such:

```
if (!ReminderList.next()) {
    -- Show that there are no records available
} else {
   while (ReminderList.next(){
      -- Show that there are record
      System.out.println(ReminderList.getString("ReminderID"));
   }
}
```

The if..else condition works perfectly and if there are records, the system does enter the else system. However, it does not enter the while loop. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already called `next()` once (in the `if`). I think the easiest solution is to change the `else` to a `do-while` like,

```
do {
  // -- Show that there are record
  System.out.println(ReminderList.getString("ReminderID"));
} while (ReminderList.next());
```